# Как будто сетевуха полетела

Tags: сеть, ubuntu

Сижу на УБУНТУ 10,04. Пытаюсь настроить инт по выделенке.  Связь через сплиттер. Втыкаю провод - лампочка на компе не мигает - хотя хозяин сказал, что сетевуху новую вот только что поставил новую. Вот ссылка на [схему подключения][1]. Делаю ifconfig выдает![снимок][2]  [1]: http://irkutsk.wstream.ru/karta/setup/manual.php  [2]: [http://i.imgur.com/ZzJJ6.jpgЧто](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jRME.jpg) делать?

Comment: Не пойму, почему вы связываете между собой два независимых факта: подключение АДСЛ модема через сплиттер и соединение между компьютером и модемом?Попробуйте тем же кабелем соединиться с другим компьютером (ноутбуком).

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что ваша сетевая карта не поддерживается. Судя по mac-адресу производитель вашей сетевой карты - ECS (предположу, что встроенная в материнку). На странице [поддерживаемых](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsWiredNetworkCards) данный производитель отсутствует.